# I accidently started and canceled a fast sync with the blockchain almost fully downloaded, its at the beginning

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

I accidently started and canceled a fast sync with the blockchain almost fully downloaded. Now its at the beginning again when I start Mist. How can I get it to recognize the old blockchain.